# Would this question on Travel.se be appropriate to migrate to here?

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118246/why-would-a-plane-only-be-able-to-be-moved-by-its-pilot) over on Travel.se asking why a plane could only be moved by its pilot, and received a comment saying it would probably be a better fit for this site. Would it be a better fit here, or is Travel.se appropriate for it? If you guys want it, I can flag it for migration to here.

Answer (score 4):

Since it does not seem to be about the "passenger side", I would expect it to be fine here, particularly if you focus on the regulation side (i.e. "is there a regulation that mandates so-and-so?"). But wait to see if it gets closed on Travel first, or ask the mods there (maybe in chat) if they feel it needs to be migrated.